# Imagens não carregam no safari e iphone

Tags: wordpress, imagem, safari

Finalizei um site em Wordpress e o mesmo não carrega as imagens tanto no Safari quanto no Iphone.

Comment: Já viu este [post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32257/como-resolver-problemas-de-upload-de-imagens-no-wordpress)?

Comment: Valeu cara, vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: Infelizmente esse post não me ajuda, mas muito obrigado pela força. Primeira pergunta feita por aqui.

Comment: Dá algum erro no console do browser?

Comment: Verifiquei melhor e vi que só não aparece no Safari as imagens em .png.
Só fica uma "interrogação" no lugar da imagem.

Obs: Imagens em jpg ta abrindo normal no Safari.

Comment: Mais uma atualização no problema, verifiquei que as fotos quebram em png e algumas coisas de posicionamento, só na versão Versão 8.0.8 (10600.8.9) do Safari.

Testei na versão 10 e funcionou tudo normalmente.

Comment: A url das imagens que já havia subido estão com acento.
Encontrei um script pra colocar no functions.php mas o acento ainda permanece na url, sabem me dizer se esse script só fará efeito nas próximas imagens que subir, ou ele já deveria ter tirado o acento mesmo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui solucionar o problema, adicionando o seguinte script, mas com prioridade em 90

```
/* Remover acento da url das imagens (Para abrir normalmente no Safari)*/
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'ck_image_attrs', 90 ); 

function ck_image_attrs($attrs)
{
  foreach ($attrs as $name => $value)
  {
    if ('src' != $name)
    {
      break;
    }
    $attrs[$name] = ck_fix_image_url($value);
  }
  return $attrs;
}

function ck_fix_image_url($url)
{
  $parts = parse_url($url);
  $path = explode('/', $parts['path']);
  $path = array_map('rawurlencode', $path);
  $path = implode('/', $path);
  return str_replace($parts['path'], $path, $url);
}
```

<sup>Fonte: https://gustavostraube.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/solucao-wordpress-e-imagens-com-acentuacao-no-safari/</sup>